# How jetty server can be integrated with apache server?

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, web, apache2

I am developing an web application where some existing part is written already in php and for that apache server is being used. But now i have to complete rest of module in Java using jetty web server. Is there any way to integrate jetty webserver with existing apache webserver so that i can simply deploy as war file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Jetty is a servlet container similar to tomcat. There are instructions here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache#Configuring_Apache

Comment: Thank you for the link. But I have already gone through the link, but could not understand clearly, as my httpd.conf file does not have any property regarding proxy, like ProxyPreserveHost, ProxyRequests etc. Can you please tell whether I have to add those properties or any other way to do?

Comment: Yes, you have to add them. There are hundreds of valid properties that can be added to an httpd.conf file.

Comment: Here's another link that might be easier to follow: http://67-23-9-112.static.slicehost.net/faq?s=200-General&t=apache